# Stripe test environment: Is there a way to do charge immediately?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the test environment of Stripe to test my code. To test charges I appreciate a way to do charges that arrive at the destination immediately(so the money of the charge are available to use) without waiting days like in real life. 
Is there a way to obtain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe has a test card `4000000000000077`, and evergreen test token,  `tok_bypassPending`, that make funds immediately available for use.

> Charge succeeds and funds will be added directly to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance).

From https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses